# What to read to get familiar with Thanos?

Tags: marvel, avengers, suggested-order, thanos

I understand the Marvel villain [Thanos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanos) has been around since the 70's.  I grew up largely on DC comics though, so I'm only vaguely familiar with him.  What are good Thanos stories to read to get up to speed with the character, and in which order?  Preferably, I'd like stories that are currently available in trade paperback collections, so it's easy and affordable for me to procure them.

Comment: I'm a bit curious what makes this less of a recommendation question than the one I asked a couple of days ago that you closed?

Comment: @DVK Start a meta question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've read some great stories involving Thanos, but haven't read all of them. Here's a short list of the essentials I was recommended. The most *interesting*, is the last one on the list, **The End**, which I recommend reading after becoming familiar with Thanos.

1. [Infinity Gauntlet](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0785156593)
2. [Infinity War](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0785121056)
3. [Infinity Crusade Vol. 1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0785131272)
4. [Infinity Crusade Vol. 2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0785131280)
5. [Marvel Universe: The End](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0785145710)

I think this list is short enough to at least get you started. Typically stories that involve Thanos, has to deal with the entire Marvel universe, so it does help to be familiar with other Marvel characters, especially [Silver Surfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_Surfer).

Answer (score 24):

## The Mad God Thanos

The earliest tales of [Thanos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanos) are some of the best. Considered one of the greatest creations of the controversial artist-writer, Jim Starlin, Thanos is a mysterious and unknown [Eternal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternals_%28comics%29), difficult to understand, whose complex machinations and motivations were unfathomable. During the stories with [Adam Warlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adam_Warlock), [Captain Marvel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Marvel_%28Marvel_Comics%29) and the Avengers, Thanos is in rare form for a comic villain and these are some of the best Thanos stories EVER.

[image]

> **The Life of Captain Marvel** (collects Iron Man #55, Captain Marvel #25-34, and Marvel Feature #12, 1991, ISBN 0-87135-635-X)
>
> **Essential Avengers:** Volume 6 (includes Captain Marvel #33 and The Avengers #125 and 135, 576 pages, February 2008, ISBN 0-7851-3058-6)
>
> **The Greatest Battles of the Avengers** (includes Avengers Annual #7, 156 pages, December 1993, ISBN 0-87135-981-2)
>
> **Essential Marvel Two-in-One: Volume 2** (includes Marvel Two-in-One Annual #2, 568 pages, July 2007, ISBN 0-7851-2698-8)
>
> **Marvel Masterworks Warlock:** Volume 2 (includes Warlock (vol. 1) #9-11, 15, Avengers Annual #7 and Marvel Two-in-One Annual #2, hardcover, 320 pages, June 2009, ISBN 0-7851-3511-1)
>
> **The Death of Captain Marvel** (collects Captain Marvel #34, Marvel Spotlight #1-2 and Marvel Graphic Novel #1, 128 pages, hardcover, June
> 2010, ISBN 0-7851-4627-X)
>
> **Silver Surfer: Rebirth Of Thanos** (collects Silver Surfer #34-38, The Thanos Quest miniseries, and "The Final Flower!" from Logan's Run #6, 224 pages

## Thanos: Worshipper of Death

The Infinity Gauntlet was an amazing series of stories where they developed the mysterious gems of power, known only as the [Infinity Gems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity_Gems), whose pedigree and origins were unknown and at the time very mysterious. The only gem we knew at the time with any certainty was the Soul Gem, which was in the possession of Adam Warlock. All the others were hinted at but finally revealed when Thanos quests for them to create the Infinity Gauntlet in his continued efforts to impress Mistress Death.

[image]
[image]

> **Infinity Gauntlet** (collects Infinity Gauntlet limited series, 256 pages, March 2000, ISBN 0-87135-944-8, December 2004, ISBN
> 0-7851-0892-0, July 2006, ISBN 0-7851-2349-0, hardcover, August 2010,
> ISBN 0-7851-4549-4)
>
> **Infinity War** (collects Infinity War limited series, Warlock and the Infinity Watch #7-10, and Marvel Comics Presents #108-111, 400
> pages, April 2006, ISBN 0-7851-2105-6)
>
> **Infinity Crusade:** Volume 1 (collects Infinity Crusade #1-3, Warlock Chronicles #1-3, and Warlock and the Infinity Watch #18-19,
> 248 pages, December 2008, ISBN 0-7851-3127-2)
>
> Volume 2 (collects Infinity Crusade #4-6, Warlock Chronicles #4-5, and
> Warlock and the Infinity Watch #20-22, 248 pages, February 2009, ISBN
> 0-7851-3128-0)
>
> **Thor: Blood and Thunder** (collects Thor (1966) #468-471, Silver Surfer (1987) #86-88, Warlock Chronicles #6-8, and Warlock and the
> Infinity Watch #23-25, 336 pages, softcover, July 2011, ISBN
> 978-0-7851-5094-7)
>
> **Infinity Abyss** (collects Infinity Abyss limited series, 176 pages, 2003, ISBN 0-7851-0985-4)

## Penitent Thanos

In this momentary period Thanos is finally over his obsession with Death and having destroyed and rebuilt reality at least twice, he is in an introspective mood and looking for new purpose. The stories are deep, psychological tales where the mythos of Thanos is rebuilt and renewed.

> **Thanos: The End** (collects Marvel: The End limited series, 160 pages, May 2004, ISBN 0-7851-1116-6)
>
> **Thanos:** Epiphany (collects Thanos #1-6, 144 pages, June 2004, ISBN 0-7851-1355-X) Samaritan (collects Thanos #7-12, 144 pages, October
> 2004, ISBN 0-7851-1540-4)

## Thanos Unleashed

The Annihilation series rewrites the Universe as we know it and Thanos has returned to being one of the scariest things in a very scary universe. Lots of space and cosmic heroes get a major make-over and the stories are some of the finest space stories Marvel has told in their entire history. If you don't pick up any of these  (The Death of Captain Marvel is the exception, ALWAYS get that) then make sure you get to the Annihilation series of books. They ROCKED!

[image]

Image shows: [Galactus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactus), [Moondragon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moondragon), [Nova](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nova_%28comics%29), [Annihilus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilus), [Ronan the Accuser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronan_the_Accuser), [Silver Surfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_Surfer), [Drax the Destroyer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drax_the_Destroyer)

> **[Annihilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilation_%28comics%29):** Volume 1 (collects [Drax the Destroyer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drax_the_Destroyer) miniseries, "Annihilation: Prologue" one-shot and Annihilation: Nova miniseries,
> 256 pages, hardcover, March 2007, ISBN 0-7851-2511-6, softcover,
> October 2007, ISBN 0-7851-2901-4)
>
> **Volume 2** (collects Annihilation: Ronan miniseries, Annihilation:
> Silver Surfer miniseries and Annihilation: Super-Skrull miniseries,
> 320 pages, hardcover, May 2007, ISBN 0-7851-2512-4, softcover,
> November 2007, ISBN 0-7851-2902-2)
>
> **Volume 3** (collects "Annihilation: The Nova Corps Files"
> one-shot/handbook, Annihilation limited series and Annihilation:
> Heralds Of Galactus miniseries, 304 pages, hardcover, July 2007, ISBN
> 0-7851-2513-2, softcover, December 2007, ISBN 0-7851-2903-0)
>
> **The Thanos Imperative** (collects The Thanos Imperative #1-6, The Thanos Imperative: Ignition, The Thanos Imperative: Devastation, and
> the Thanos Sourcebook, 248 pages, hardcover, February 2011, ISBN
> 0-7851-5183-4)

Comment: Thaddeus, does he need to read all of these to get familiar with Thanos?

Comment: Of course not. I broke them into three separate periods. He could choose to read each of them, all of them or none of them. 
I like to assume a person may start learning and like to continue. If so, they have one source and don't have to hunt around. I also assume someone who already has familiarity with Thanos might still like the opportunity to learn something new.

Comment: That's a great way to split it up, but at a cursory glance it looks like one long list. Perhaps you could split it with sub-headings, using ### ?

Answer (score 1):

The infinity books all paint the interesting and creator-designed nature of Thanos. Given another good writer, his style of speech is at least maintained but he reverts to simplistic villainy. Giffen (Annihilation, Thanos 6-12) and Marz (later Silver Surfer) can do this. Few if any others can be trusted to give him the proper justified arrogance and caustic dimissal of others exhibited in his speech patterns. Starlin alone makes him the fully rounded and fascinating character that has captivated me personally for two thirds of my life. I don't recommend anything Starlin himself didn't write. Gauntlet War Crusade Abyss...

Again, other good writers have touched him but they flatten him out basically without exception. The elusive story "Yule Memory" from the 1992 Holiday Special exemplifies the complexity of Thanos in a single story. And shows you everything that everyone else ignores or forgets when writing him. Despite the number of times Starlin made it painstakingly clear.